# Bash script to read txt file, do a while loop and write output

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I'm fairly new to bash scripting, and I wrote the following script to read a text file, run a while loop with if statements, and write the data I want into another text file.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
#
variable1=0
variable2=0
variable3=0
variable4=0
cat input.txt | while read Column1 Column2 Column3

do
    if ["$Column1" = variable2]; then
        if ["$Column2" > variable3 && "$Column2" < variable4]; then
            if ["$Column3" > variable4]; then
                variable4="$Column3"
                continue
            fi
        else
            echo variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4
            variable1++
            variable3="$Column2"
            variable4="$Column3"
        fi
    else
        echo variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4
        variable1++
        variable2="$Column1"
        variable3="$Column2"
        variable4="$Column3"
    fi

done>output.txt
```

However when I run the script I get the following error message:

```
./code.sh: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
'/code.sh: line 31: `done>output.txt
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me with this!

Comment: bash is space aware. It's `[ "$Column1"` not `["$Col...`

Comment: `>` is used by the shell for redirection. Safer to use `[[ ... > ... ]]` in bash, or `[ ... \> .. ]`. `&&` is not valid inside `[ ... ]` (bash will warn you). Test your code with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) until it doesn't find any more problems.

Comment: `<` is a lexical comparison, not a numerical comparison.

Comment: Get in the habit now of using `test` instead of `[`.  You are making the classic mistake of thinking that `[` is an operator, or at the very least that it is a token in the language.  It is not.  It is just a command. As such, there needs to be whitespace between it and its first argument.

Comment: Also, its last argument must be exactly the string `]`.  It cannot be `variable2]`

Comment: `variable1++` will cause bash to attempt to run a command with that name, not increment it which needs something like `(( variable1++ ))`

Comment: `echo variable1` does not refer to the value of any variable, it just outputs the string provided. Use `echo "$variable1"` to use a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do but there are a lot of things one can fail in bash, i posted a tested version.

[image: this works for me]

p.s. I was criticized that the code is a picture :)) here you have it for copy paste

```
#!/bin/bash
let variable1=0
let variable2=0
let variable3=0
let variable4=0
cat input.txt | while read Column1 Column2 Column3


do
    if [ "x$Column1" == "x$variable2" ]; then
        if [ "x$Column2" -gt "x$variable3" ]  &&  [ "x$Column2" -lt "x$variable4" ]; then
            if [ "x$Column3" -gt "x$variable4" ]; then
                let variable4=$Column3
                continue
            fi
        else
            echo $variable1 $variable2 $variable3 $variable4
            let "variable1 += 1"
            let variable3=$Column2
            let variable4=$Column3
        fi
    else
        echo $variable1 $variable2 $variable3 $variable4
        let "variable1 += 1"
        let variable2=$Column1
        let variable3=$Column2
        let variable4=$Column3
    fi

done > output.txt
```